# display element in ascending or descending order using bubble sort in java

Tags: java, bubble-sort

i'm having problem to display letters ether they are in ascending order or not, the logic it seem is right by assuming  array in ascending order, but always got the wrong result when i print them, i've tried the other way around but always got the wrong result.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print( "#Enter text : " );
        String text = BIO.getString();

        boolean inorder = false;
        while ( ! text.equals( "END" ) )
          {
            inorder = true;
            // Convert the above string to a char array.
            char[] arr = text.toCharArray();

            for (int i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++)
            { //Check pair

               if ( arr[i] > arr[i + 1] ) {

               inorder = false;
               break;

              }

            }


            if ( inorder ) {

             System.out.printf( text + " is in ascending order\n" ); 


            }

            else {

             System.out.printf( text + " is not in ascending order\n" );

            }

            System.out.print( "#Enter text : " );
            text = BIO.getString();


       }
    }
}
```

Comment: What output did you get?  What did you expect?  What did you learn when you ran your code in the debugger?

Comment: Can you provide an example on which this code works wrong?

Comment: Please add 'homework' tag to such questions

Comment: And what does this have to do with bubble sort?

Comment: The code is fine, though you just doing more steps when you can restrict yourself by simply do the checking part with this **if (text.charAt(i) > text.charAt(i + 1))** The issue is with the value returned by getString() method. And you still using printf thingy in java.

Comment: if they require to ignore letter case, do i necessarily need to add something else ?

Answer (score 1):

The above code works fine, Maybe the problem is in the value returned by `BIO.getString()`. Also in the title you mention a bubble sort algorithm, where's the code for that? it's possible that the problem lies there.

**EDIT:**

Now that you've mentioned that the problem is with upper/lowercase words, I may suggest that you just convert the input text to lowercase before comparing, like this:

```
char[] arr = text.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
```

In that way, it won't matter if the text is in upper or lowercase.

Comment: I confirm that the above code works fine, even with non-english characters. Also, the above code displays the string that it checks, so it should be easy to check whether it is telling the truth by just looking at program output, unless that BIO.getString() function does something nasty, such as embedding some non-printable character like zero in the string.

Comment: the problem is when i input word for example  "knotty" will give me result " is in ascending order " but when put capital letter in the begining and the end of the word "KnottY" it gives me result " is not in ascending order " could you pleasee help, thanks

Comment: @user761980 I edited my answer, please check it to see if it works for you. You should have mentioned from the very beginning that you were having trouble with upper/lowercase.